# cx_freeze executable - Py_Initialize: Unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze

I'm using cx_freeze to pack my Python script as a standalone executable.
The exe is running fine on the machine it was packed (with python 3.5 and all the relevant packages).

But when I copied the folder cx_freeze created to another machine the I got this error:
[image]

My cx_freeze script:

```
import sys
import numpy
import os.path
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'


setup(
    name = "DocSum",
    version = "1.0",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["idna","asyncio", "encodings","numpy", "jinja2.ext"]}},
    description = "DocSumRESTfulServer",
    executables = [Executable("DocSumRESTfulServer.py", base = None)]
    )
```

Any idea what could be the reason? I thought that the exe should be a standalone (run on machines without python). Am I wrong?

Comment: Unless you need to use `cx_freeze` for some reason, you could also try PyInstaller, which does the same thing.

Comment: yes - cx_freeze when I last time used it :) had issues of not including all dependencies like MS redist, etc - so you obviously miss something on the other pc that you have to manually add to package when do installer of your prog

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
I also got dependencies as `underthesea` and `sumy` that are not packed with pyinstaller. I compare all installed components between the machines and they are identical. I'm really lost, if you got any other ideas I will be glad to hear.

Comment: If it helps: I packed the 2 exes on 2 different machines and they both work only on the machine they were packed and not on the other.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that not all dependencies were compiled successfully.
If you want to have a standalone executable, I recommend *pyinstaller*.

Just pip install it then:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile  yourFile.py
```

The --onefile flag is used to package everything into a single executable. Your executable file would be found on the *dist* folder.

You could also try this [site](https://pytoexe.com/).

Comment: How to follow `sym_links` on a executable ? **Your system never provide it !** like this : `numpy` doesn't work on his application.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As metioned above, I also got dependencies as `underthesea` and `sumy` that are not packed with pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. At the end I discovered that I need to copy also my `python37.dll` and the `lib` directory.
If the exe, dll and the directory are on the same directory, it works.

I would like to have a single exe too.